# Leave Management System in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am developing Leave Management System in SharePoint 2013. Employees can apply for leaves and Manager can either approve or reject it.

I have accomplished this by creating a new list - "Leaves" and starting a workflow when a new item gets added. Workflow sends an email to Manager and creates a task item for him to be able to approve or reject it.

1. However, I would like to know if this approach is preferable in real time scenario. Suppose for organization of 500 employees, can a single list hold so many records for all employees. What are possible ways here to utilize the features in SharePoint and also create a scalable application.
2. Also, I am also planning to develop a new Add-in in SharePoint 2013 since for applying new leave, we need to display additional information such as available leaves and do some custom validations which are not provided by default SharePoint list. I will be adding the new item to the SharePoint list from the custom developed page so that the workflow still is intact and I am still utilizing out-of-box SharePoint features. Is this the way to go for enterprise level application or there are any other alternatives. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Lists are capable of holding that much data. I don't see a problem if you use a single list to hold leave request of 500 employees.

Assume a worst case scenario that all of the 500 employee apply 25 leaves individually in a year, then the item count would be (500*25= 12500) which is not bad.

You will need to take care of the `List Threshold` error, because data is greater than 5000. For this you can create views which always bring out results less than 5000.

Now lets say you have plan for 5 years, so each year you will add 12500 items which at the end of 5 years will be 12500*5 = 62500 items

Here you can think of 2 options

1. You can create a list for each year, i.e. Leaves2016, Leaves2017 etc.
2. In a single list create folders of year, and inside them add all leave datas.

> **Note**: The only major thing you need to take care of List view threshold problem. Which can be tackled with intelligently designing
>   views

For your second question.

I agree that the OOB SharePoint List form will not cater your requirements. So creating a custom page an add in or something else is a way to go. As far as your data is getting inserted into a list and eventually activating a workflow there is no harm in it.